# How to choose earliest NRF week number, from a set of date ranges in python?

Tags: python, date

I have a list of 104 consecutive weeks.  The week numbers come from the National Retail Foundation Calendar.  So week 1 will basically be the first week in February.

I'm finding ranges of weeks inside this two year list of dates.  I'll assume just two ranges for the point of my question.  I want to pick the weeks that give me the largest range.

When the ranges are in the middle of the years, it's easy, I just pick the earliest start, and latest end.

Example:
Range 1: 2010-04-09 (NRF Week 10) through 2010-07-16 (NRF Week 24)
Range 2: 2011-04-01 (NRF Week 9) through 2011-06-24 (NRF Week 21)
I'll choose start of 9, end of 24. Just a simple min() or max() function.

When the ranges start/end around the start/end of the year, this gets more complicated.
Example:
Range 1: 2010-02-12 (NRF Week 2)  through 2010-05-14 (NRF Week 15).
Range 2: 2011-01-28 (NRF Week 52) through 2011-04-29 (NRF Week 13).
I need to choose start 52, end 15.  min() no longer works for the start.

Or even worse, if the weeks are 1 and 47, I need to choose 47.

I'd like to find a way that will pick the best (earliest or latest) in both situations.
I'm not finding a straight forward approach to doing this.  Has anyone run into this problem before or may be able to offer a solution?

I appreciate any help you might be able to give.

Thank you.

Comment: Range 1 in your second example is from a later date to a past date, it is the only range where the first date is after the second date.  Is that intentional or is it a typo?

Comment: If you've got 104 weeks, can you call weeks from this year 0--51 and weeks from the next year 52--103?

Comment: @F.J Yes, it was a typo, thank you.  I've fixed it.

Comment: @sarnold Yes, I should be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you simply want to ignore the year in your comparison function (to find the min/max dates).  Since your data set is small, why not just iterate over all weeks and perform comparisons based on month & date only?

Comment: You mean just pick the min day/month from each?
That breaks down when I want 2010-12-31 (wk48) over 2012-02-03 (wk1).

Comment: It would be useful to clearly specify what you're looking for.  My best guess at this point is that you are translating normal dates to a mathematical group representation (NRF Week #) and taking a difference there.  Have you tried subtracting 52 when the earlier date has a larger week # than the latter date?